# Rancher server don't show two rancher agents running on two different hosts

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, rancher

We created a cluster with two hosts and on one of them, we ran a Rancher-server and a rancher-agent. In the other just the rancher-agent. But when we started the second agent (it does not matter which agent starts before) on the Rancher console we could see just one agent and after that, the Rancher server crashed.

We tried to remove all docker's configuration with the following command

- docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
- sudo rm -rf rancher-mysql/
- sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker

but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

**We found what caused the problem and the solution**.

The two VM hosts has been created as a clone of another VM with Rancher already installed on it. In this case on both new hosts there were present the directory /var/lib/rancher and the same identical file /etc/docker/key.json.
Remove the key.json file didn't solved the problem but we fixed it removing also the **/var/lib/rancher** directory